# Example in dimension theory

Tags: dimension-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, examples

Could you give me an example of a complete metric space wiht covering dimension $> n$ all of which compact subsets have covering dimension $\le n$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A guess**

In $l^2$ Hilbert space, consider the set $E$ of points with all coordinates rational.  Erdös ([reference](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1968851)) showed that $E$ has topological dimension $1$.  (In separable metric space, all notions of topological dimension coincide.)

Does this $E$ have the property that every compact subset is zero-dimensional?  This space (and thus any subset of it) is totally disconnected, and isn't it the case that for compact (metric) spaces, this implies zero-dimensinal?

Comment: @Gerald: I can't quite figure out how compactness can be used to rule out the element on the boundary that Erdos constructed. Help please? 

Comment: Thank you, I add "completeness" but Erdös constructs also a complete set ($R_1$). It seems to work, but I need to think a bit.

Comment: @Willie, If your set $K$ is compact then there is projection $\pi:K\to\mathbb R^n$ to a coordinate n-plane such that preimage of a set of small diameter has small diameter --- from this you get that $\dim K=0$

Comment: Yes, complete Erdös-space (all sequences with only irrational coordinates) is complete, separable, dim= 1, and totally disconnected, so this example will do for the complete case.

Comment: Why does the Erdös space or its irrational variation admit a complete metrics?

Comment: Actually, it's clear that the Erdös space doesn't. I am not sure about the irrational version but I doubt about it admitting a complete metrics.

Comment: Set $R_1$ (all sequences with only irrational coordinates) is a $G_\delta$ set, right?

Comment: I had a black-out moment or two :-). Indeed, as Gerald has written above, $\mathbb R_1$ is a $\mathbb G_\delta$ in the complete space $l^2$.