# Nonseparable example in dimension theory?

Tags: dimension-theory, mg.metric-geometry, examples, gn.general-topology

> Could you give me an example of a complete metric space with covering dimension $> n$ all of which closed separable subsets have covering dimension $\le n$?

The question closely related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43680).

Comment: time to close?  nothing since November ... but still frequently bumped to the front page.


Comment: @Gerald: Why?, maybe one day I will get an answer...

Comment: Nice question. I'd keep it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are completely metrizable spaces $X$ with $\dim(X)=1$ and $\mathrm{ind}(X)=0$, where $\dim$ denotes the covering dimension and $\mathrm{ind}$ the small inductive dimension. The first such example is due to P. Roy (see *"nonequality of dimensions for metric spaces"*, TAMS 1968), but there are many others. My favourite is due to E.K. van Douwen (see *"The small inductive dimension can be raised by the adjunction of a single point"*, Indag.Math. 1973).

Note that if $Y$ is a separable (not necessarily closed) subspace of such an $X$ then $\dim(Y)=0$ since $\dim$ and $\mathrm{ind}$ coincide for separable metrizable spaces. So any such $X$ satisfies what you want for $n=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ the river metric on the positive plane $(R^+)^2$:
$d((x,y),(u,v)) = |y-v|$ if $x=u$ and $|y| + |v| + |x-u|$ otherwise.

(the x-axis is the river, there are othogonal paths in which we can move
"as in R", while otherwise we have to go via the river first).

Let $v_x$ the vertical line by orizonatal quote $x$, then  the subspace topology of $v_x\setminus$ {$(x,0)$} is the euclidean topology, but any open that containing a point of $r_0$ the the bottom horizontal line is  non-separable (involving a no countable vertical segments) we call a such open a "b-open" .

THen any covering $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ as order 2, i.e. there exixt almost 3 elemets by no-empty intersection:

Considering a b-open $U\in \mathcal{U}$, exist a point $x\in r_o \cap (Cl(U)\setminus U)$ (i.e. in its boundary in $r_0$) then there exixt another b-open $V\in \mathcal{U}$ containing $x$, and $U\cap V$ is a b-open. The sets $U$, $V$ and $U\cap V$ are also open in the euclidean topology and we can assume also connected and containing its own projection on $r_0$, then because $R^2$ has dimension 2 follow that exist a point $(x', y)\notin U\cup V$ such that any open set containing $(x', y) $ intersect $U\cap V$ (otherwise we can make a cover of order 2, then any refinement has order 2). Then the element $F\in \mathcal{U}$ containing $(x', y)$ (like a open interval in the $v_{x'}$) meet also $U\cap V$ :

IF NO,the $sup$-extrem of the quote that $U\cap V$ can reachedin in the $v_{x'}$ vertical is minor of $y$. Any (open ball) $B_\epsilon(x)$ with $x\in r_0$ is like a halph-square triangle then if this is included in $U\cap V$ it dont meet the follow open part  $S\subset R^2$:

Considering the two halph line by base in $x',y$ at right by $45°$ pendence and $-45°$ at left (like the graph of $y=|x|$ traslated from origin to $(x', y)$) and consider the superior part $S$ of plane $R^2$ these halph-line  cut off, by these halph line included.

but then $U\cap V$ being union of (open) balls dont meet $S$, then exixt a (euclidean) open neighbord of $(x', y)$ that dont meet $U\cap V$ .

Comment: If I understand you correctly, $X$ is $\mathbb R_+$ with attached $\mathbb R_+$ to each point. In this case $X$ is 1-dimensional; i.e. your argument should be wrong somewhere...

Comment: @$\varepsilon-\delta$: No the distance is euclidean on vertical line, but for go from a pont $(x,y)$ to a point $(x’, y’)$ with $x\neq x’$ you have to go vertically from  $(x, y) $ to $(x, 0)$ then  horizontally to $(x’,0)$ then go vertically to $(x’,y’)$.

These path’s define the distance in $X$. 

PS. We can chose copy af a finite close interval instead  the vertical lines (copies of $R^+$) then any subspace compact is separable. This answere to another question in this forum.

Please I wish delete my bad formatted comment above. 

Comment: It is nearly impossible to read your comments...

Comment: The sets U, V and U∩V are NOT open in the euclidean topology!!!

Comment: I'm sorry about the mistake of latex on the comment, add Another answer

Answer (score 0):

@: $\varepsilon-\delta$: $X$ isn't the the topological sum of real lines. You consider this "more shorty paths" logic:

For move in a vertical line you go on the line. But for go from $(x, y)$  to $x', y')$  ($x\neq x'$)  you go (vertically) from $(x, y)$ to $(0, x)$ then go (horizontally) to $(x', 0)$ then go (vertically) to $(x', y').

These "more short paths" distance describe the metric of $X$.

Now  a open ball centered in $(x, 0)$ and radius $\epsilon$  is a triangle isosceles, with the top right corner (the half of a square), its hight is $\epsilon$,  and its base (intersection by the $x$-axis) is a open interval of lenght $2\epsilon$  (centered in $x$),  and the intersection by {$(x, y)\in R^2 | y>0 $} is a open euclidean triangle.

Comment: Sorry, the metric you construct, gives $\mathbb R_+$ with $\mathbb R_+$ attached to each point. And I know this is 1-dimensional...
Your statement about $\epsilon$-ball is correct, but for opens sets it is not longer true.